# Difference between LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE and LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I was reading about different lock modes supported in hibernate but couldn't understand the difference b/w LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE and LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both are exclusive locks but the second will trigger an exception if resource is busy whereas the first will wait.

the hibernate documentation is not very clear indeed.

PESSIMISTIC_WRITE : "Transaction will obtain a database lock immediately."

per opposition to

UPGRADE_NOWAIT : "Attempt to obtain an upgrade lock, using an Oracle-style select for update nowait." regarding nowait : [Oracle will wait for any locks to be released unless you specify NOWAIT](https://ss64.com/ora/select.html)

However nowait is not immediately. the "immediately" of the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE refers to the session scope (hibernate will trigger the database lock immediately instead of automatically at the first write operation as in the WRITE mode) but in this mode the database will wait for other locks to be released instead of triggering an exception if the resource is busy (it is a simple `select... for update` statement).

Note that it's very probable that not all databases support the "nowait" scheme, for example [mysql implemented it in version 8](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3597), in this case both mode will be equivalent.